# Comparisons using std::equal and equality operator

Tags: c++, floating-point, comparison, equality

In the following bit of code, I was under the impression all 3 "equality" checks were equivalent, however the last one seems to return a different result from the other 2 - *why is that the case?*

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   {
      std::vector<double> d0 { 0.0 , 1.0, 2.0};
      std::vector<double> d1 { 1.0 , 2.0, 3.0};

      d0[0] += double(1);
      d0[1] += double(1);
      d0[2] += double(1);

      if (std::equal(std::begin(d0),std::end(d0),std::begin(d1)))
         printf("equal\n");
      else
         printf("not equal\n");

      if (d0 == d1)
         printf("equal\n");
      else
         printf("not equal\n");

   }

   {
      double d0[] { 0.0 , 1.0, 2.0};
      double d1[] { 1.0 , 2.0, 3.0};

      d0[0] += double(1);
      d0[1] += double(1);
      d0[2] += double(1);

      if (std::equal(d0,d0 + sizeof(d0),d1))
         printf("equal\n");
      else
         printf("not equal\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour you're right, I've made the change it was a typo. The problem though still stands.

Comment: `sizeof` of an array returns the size of the array in bytes, not the number of elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one does not compare equal because this expression `d0 + sizeof(d0)` does not do what you expect it to. `sizeof` applied to an array evaluates to the size of the array in bytes, not the number of elements in the array. So you're not creating an iterator to one past the last element in `d0`.

Use one of these instead

```
if (std::equal(d0, d0 + sizeof(do0)/sizeof(d0[0]), d1))
```

or

```
#include <type_traits>

...

if (std::equal(d0, d0 + std::extent<decltype(d0)>::value, d1))
```

or

```
#include <iterator>

...

if (std::equal(std::begin(d0), std::end(d0), d1))
```